# Baking displacement map: Base mesh is included in the highres output

Tags: materials, texture-baking, baking, displacement

[image: displacement baking include base mesh]
**How can i get ride of all those quads so only the white mark shows up?**

**Step to reproduce**

1. Create sphere as *base*
2. Duplicate *base* as *hd* and add x3 subdivision modifier then apply
3. Sculpt some details on *hd* mesh
4. Unwrap *base* and create a 32*1024*1024 texture with all faces selected
5. Set up the bake (*normalize* simply help to see through) as below

[image: baking settings for displacement map]

Answer (score 1):

[Answer from @Secrop on blenderartist.org:](https://blenderartists.org/t/baked-displacement-include-the-base-mesh-in-the-output/1141251/2?u=elise_sucet)

> **Add a subdivision modifier to the low poly object before baking.**
>
> The thing here is that each poly in the lowres object is flat, but the surface from > the highres is curved… This makes the displacement value at the center of those polys to be greater than their corners.
>   If your lowres is later to be subdivided with ‘Simple’ method, this bake will be correct. On the other hand, if you use ‘Catmull-Clark’, then you need to use this subdivision at the baking phase also.

**Result:**
[image: Blender displacement map fixed with subdivision]